# In OCaml, write a function that works Base.Map and Base.Hashtbl

Tags: ocaml

So I want to write a function that takes a first class module as an argument that works on Base.Map and Base.Hashtbl, but I'm running into a problem. This code illustrates what's going on:

```
module type Len_intf = sig
  type t
  val length : t -> int
end

let show (type a) (module L : Len_intf with type t = a) h =
  printf "len: %d\n" @@ L.length h

let test (type a) h =
  show (module Hashtbl : Len_intf with type t = a) h
```

Attempting to compile this results in:

```
Error: Signature mismatch:
   ...
   Type declarations do not match:
     type ('a, 'b) t = ('a, 'b) Poly.t
   is not included in
     type t
   They have different arities.
   File "test.ml", line 2, characters 2-8:
     Expected declaration
   File "src/hashtbl_intf.ml", line 552, characters 2-17:
     Actual declaration
```

Is this even possible, due to the different type arity of Hashtbl and Map?

Answer (score 0):

Writing a function that takes a first-class module is certainly possible (you did so), and it can be called like that:

```ml
let test (type a) (type b) h =
  let module M = struct
      type t = (a,b) Hashtbl.t
      let length = Hashtbl.length
    end in
  show (module M) h
```

But I do not think it is possible to do it the way you want. Indeed, type equalities come afterwards, in addition to what the signature already describes. They cannot prevent a type arity mismatch.